# Need Help to do Login authentication oauth2.0 while load testing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, jmeter, blazemeter

I have a BlazeMeter Pro account and I am stuck on the step I try to record in Jmeter and also try with BlazeMeter recording but not able to do it.

Now flow is I have to login into the system and perform the operation, we implement oAuh2.0 from the development side to authenticate the user from the Gmail and we face issue while record script that user is not able to authenticate to login when you hit with single or multiple users.

to authenticate I need all the below parameters and I have all details but now in Jmeter or BlazeMeter, I do not understand where I add all details.
client_id=
client_secret=
refresh_token=
grant_type=refresh_token

we are implementing a following steps at record time

1. Load a respective URL and open Gmail Login page
2. After Enter email and password page is redirect and particular website will be display
3. After enter user name and password on the website UI is display.

Please guide me on how I implement this and process my flow for load testing.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google documentation in [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints) you need to

1. Send a request to [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#redirecting) with:

   - `client_id`
   - `redirect_uri`
   - `response_type`
   - `scope`

   parameters.

This request you should be able to record using your favourite recording option.

In your case you need to change this `redirect_uri` to some web server which you control as you will receive the token there in form of `https://your_redirect_url_here/callback#access_token=your_token_will_be_here&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

It's a good idea to use [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server) for this purpose.

2. Once you get the token you will be able to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to send `Authorization` header with the value of `Bearer ${your_token}`

More information:

- [OAuth 2.0 Documentation](https://oauth.net/2/)
- [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) (if your application uses different flow you can replicate it there and see relevant requests/responses which can be later on implemented in JMeter)